# Compare 2 fields with inline PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, import

I am currently importing a CSV file into my WooCommerce products. I’m trying to make it so that the sale price on products only gets showcased when {price[1]} is less then {fromprice[1]}. For this, I’m trying to use an inline PHP if-statement, but it doesn’t work. Code:

```
[IF({price[.< {fromprice}]}) ] {price} [ENDIF]
```

Whenever I click on preview it gives me the following error: Error parsing: Close brace expected instead of TEXT

Comment: I have no idea what's going on here, but I would expect things to be consistent. The `}` behind `price` seems to be in the wrong place. Perhaps something like this `[IF({price} < {fromprice})] {price} [ENDIF]` could work? Again, I say this without any knowledge... but often a wrong comment jolts someone into correcting it... 

Comment: https://gist.github.com/m-thomson/982adf4d7f680887f03658949b283096

Comment: Basically, I'm importing a CSV file into my WooCommerce products on my wordpress site. I want sale prices to only showcase when the value {price} is less than {fromprice}

Comment: See, I got it all wrong. Given that documentation I would try: `[IF({price[.<../fromprice]})]{price}[ENDIF]`.

Comment: Man I can not put my thankfullness into words. God bless you.

Comment: It works? Wow, that is a surprise to me as well.

Comment: It does! I've just tested it with several previews from different products and it works correctly.

Comment: Miracles do exist. Have fun working with your site.

Comment: For the avoidance of future confusion, that is not "an inline PHP if-statement", it is a mix of XPath and a custom macro language unique to that particular WordPress plugin.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.